# Laravel Configuration

Tags: laravel, configuration, virtualhost, web-development-server

I have been trying to configure Laravel but it seems to have some kind of error: "IP address could not be found."

This is my configuration in my httpd-vhost.conf
[Configuration on httpd-vhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2CiL.png)

and this is what I put in my host
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmBIt.png)

I tried restarting and checking my syntax through httpd.exe -t in apache but it seems okay

Comment: Have you tried Homestead?

Comment: Haven't tried it yet. I will look into that. But is there an error on what I did?

Comment: Honestly, I'll have to leave that up to someone else. I use Laravel professionally and we all use Homestead because it mimics the setup of a dedicated server without us spending the time to set it up. But I don't doubt it's worth learning- I know I've done it at least once.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

In your `httpd-vhost.conf` file write this, If you want virtual host of **reviewer** then try this,

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName reviewer.test
  ServerAlias reviewer.test
  DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/reviewer/public"
  DirectoryIndex index.php
  <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/reviewer/public">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And in your **hosts** file write this,

```
127.0.0.1       reviewer.test
```

> Then **restart** your all xampp server services.

**Problem in your files**

You haven't removed the comment ( `#` this symbol represents that it is comment.)

This is your file configuration.

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
#   127.0.0.1       reviewer.dev
```

You have to remove `#` this symbol, and replace `dev` with `test` . Get more knowledge from [this link.](https://laravel-news.com/chrome-63-now-forces-dev-domains-https)

```
# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
    127.0.0.1       reviewer.test
```

I hope this stuff will help you.

Comment: Great :) You can accept the answer and upvote also as an appreciation this will be the reward for me in stackoverflow .

Comment: @SofiaMallari Please accept my answer(for marked as an answer) because you found it helpful. And other stack users will know that this answer is correct for your question no need to find other answer for you.  [Check this tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)